# Range Summation of Array

Tags: algorithm

We are giving Array `A` and two type of query

1. Change `F[x] = V`
2. Find the Summation from `[1.R]` with `d = x` .i.e `sum (1, 1+x, 1+2x, ...)`

I know fro `x = 1` it can be done with **BIT** or **Segment Tree**, but how do if `d > 1`?

Comment: Would a O(Q.sqrt(n).log(n)) approach be fast enough where Q is the number of queries and n the length of the array?

Comment: It's unclear, for point 2 what are the input parameters?

Comment: @Sorin for 2 query `R` and `d` is given